# CCLayerColor in SpriteKit

Tags: drawing, sprite-kit

Is there something to replace CCLayerColor, CCLayerGradient etc inside Sprite Kit?

It was always easy to create simple filled rectangles in cocos2d, but I don't find any out of the box solutions in Sprite Kit so far.

As always, it should be platform independent so no iOS only code please (i.e., inside Sprite Kit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
SKSpriteNode *rect = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(70, 70)];
```

Comment: Thanks. I incorrectly assumed a SKSpriteNode needed a texture.

Comment: no problem, this is a decent intro from apple if you havent seen yet https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW1